# What is the derivative of $\arcsin(x/4)$?

Tags: calculus

I tried it and got $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}}$

But WolframAlpha is saying that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$

What did I do wrong, and what is the correct way of solving it? Thanks

Comment: You did nothing wrong: the two expressions are equal.

Answer (score 5):

$$4\sqrt{1-x^2/16}=\sqrt{16(1-x^2/16)}=\sqrt{16-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's the same answer just simplified. 
$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}(16-x^2})}=\frac{1}{{4}\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{16-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$